# How to I resolve "expected command" in NetLogo?

Tags: command, netlogo, patch, brackets, memory-movement

I'm trying to get turtles in Netlogo to "stay put" for 20 clicks, before moving on (just going forward), but I keep getting "expected command" errors. Any idea where my bracketing is incorrect?

Thanks!

```
to solar-battery  ;; trying to ask turtles to move forward after being stationary for 20 
clicks
ask turtles [
[ifelse (patch-here = destination)                                   
[
if (ticks - ticks-since-here > ticks-to-stay-on-patch patch-here) 
[
set ticks-since-here 20
set destination one-of patch]]]
[face destination
forward 1
if [patch-here = destination]
[set ticks-since-here ticks]]]
end
```

Comment: I would first recommend you format your code so the relationship between open brackets and closed brackets is very clear. Open brackets on the left. Matching close brackets line up under them. Also indent your code to make the logic easier to follow. Do this and I think you will instantly find the error. If I could edit your question to do that to the code--your question would answer itself.  Finally--look at your use of the `PATCH` command--once you fix the first error, that's going to cause another one.

Answer (score 0):

### Supporting Ideas

Since comments don't allow newlines and indenting... here's a sample of code formatting. As you become more skilled, you can experiment with other formatting schemes, but until then, strict code formatting is one method of "automatic debugging" that can help you prevent some kinds of basic errors--so you can focus on the tricky ones.

```
to do-stuff
  ask turtles with [ pxcor > 0 ] ;; this is fine.
  [ ;; open of code block
    jump 1
    if (pcolor = white)
    [ ;; open code block
      rt 90 jump 1
    ] ;; close block
  ] ;; close block
end
```

One place where other arrangements of brackets HELP rather than confuse is when simulating a SWITCH structure:

When doing a switch, keep the conditions and actions VERY SHORT. If they are long, wrap the conditions in a reporter. Likewise, wrap the action in a procedure, unless it is VERY SHORT.

```
if-else (condition1) [ action 1 ][
if-else (condition2) [ action 2 ][
if-else (condition3) [ action 3 ][
if-else (condition4) [ action 4 ][
;; OTHERWISE
    default-action
]]]] ;; one close bracket for each condition.
```

This format makes it VERY easy to add, remove, or re-order conditions, without having to mess with moving brackets, changing indents, or mismatching brackets.

### The Solution

EDIT TO ADD: Here is the code from the question again, reformatted. Can you see the error now?

```
to solar-battery
  ;; trying to ask turtles to move forward
  ;; after being stationary for 20 clicks
  ask turtles
  [ 
    [ ifelse (patch-here = destination)                                   
      [
        if (ticks - ticks-since-here > ticks-to-stay-on-patch patch-here) 
        [
           set ticks-since-here 20
           set destination one-of patch
        ]
      ]
    ] 
    [
      face destination
      forward 1
      if [patch-here = destination]
      [
        set ticks-since-here ticks
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Expected Command Hint:

> After the first bracket, NetLogo expects a command. But you have another level of brackets. So you get the error: Expected Command.